# Verifying that an event did happen

Tags: solidity, dapp-development, events

I want my contract to check that a claimed event was indeed logged.

Assuming I know how to follow a merkle path from a recent block and find the bit patterns of a log entry, how in solidity do I get the bit patterns from the claimed event object, so I may compare the two?

Also, how from the source code do I extract the topic and the bit pattern encoding, so I may do the same job from my client and server programs, outside of the contract itself?

PS: I suspect that at least part of the answer lies in the [Solidity ABI Spec](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/abi-spec.html#events), but for the neophyte that I am, there is information or meta-information missing, such that I'm not sure how to interpret all that data. Examples and/or code would help.

Answer (score 1):

Contracts have no access to what you refer to, they just emit events. Find more information in [this](https://media.consensys.net/technical-introduction-to-events-and-logs-in-ethereum-a074d65dd61e) article.

From outside of the contract, you can use [web3](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id38) .